# Slice strings in .txt and return only one of the new strings

Tags: python, string, slice

I want to use lines of strings of a .txt file as search queries in other .txt files. But before this, I need to slice those strings of the lines of my original text data. Is there a simple way to do this?

This is my original .txt data:

```
    CHEMBL2057820|MUBD_HDAC2_ligandset|mol2|42|dock12
    CHEMBL1957458|MUBD_HDAC2_ligandset|mol2|58|dock10
    CHEMBL251144|MUBD_HDAC2_ligandset|mol2|41|dock98
    CHEMBL269935|MUBD_HDAC2_ligandset|mol2|30|dock58
    ... (over thousands)
```

And I need to have a new file where the new new lines contain only part of those strings, like:

```
CHEMBL2057820
CHEMBL1957458
CHEMBL251144
CHEMBL269935
```

Comment: this is simple readlines and `split('|')` What did you try so far?

Comment: @Arpit Solanki I was able to split but only for one line. I could not do for the all data. Moreover I wanted to keep only the first string after splitting

Comment: see the answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file, read in the lines and split each line at the `|` character, then index the first result

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    parts = (line.lstrip().split('|', 1)[0] for line in f)
    with open('dest.txt', 'w') as dest:
        dest.write("\n".join(parts))
```

Explanation:

- `lstrip` - removes whitespace on leading part of the line
- `split("|")` returns a list like: `['CHEMBL2057820', 'MUBD_HDAC2_ligandset', 'mol2', '42', 'dock12']` for each line
- Since we're only conerned with the first section it's redundant to split the rest of the contents of the line on the `|` character, so we can specify a maxsplit argument, which will stop splitting the string after it's encoutered that many chacters
- So `split("|", 1)`
  gives`['CHEMBL2057820','MUBD_HDAC2_ligandset|mol2|42|dock12']`
- Since we're only interested in the first part `split("|", 1)[0]` returns 
  the `"CHEMBL..."` section

Comment: This solved my problem. I just did not understand much how it did.

Answer (score 0):

Use [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) and readlines:

```
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    g = open('bar.txt')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        l = line.strip().split('|')[0]
        g.write(l)
```

Comment: the code did not work. Is 'foo' and 'bar' not meant to the input text and output text respectively?

Comment: foo. and bar are filenames. foo must be your input file and bar will be output file. I assume that you are using linux so extension is not compulsory

Comment: But it was exactly how I used. There is an error but it does not say where unfortunatelly

Comment: post the traceback in the question if you are having problems